# Foruier Series coefficients.

Tags: integration

I am given a following signal and want to calculate it's Fourier series coefficients:

$$      x(t) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
          0 & \quad 0< t < 2 \\            
           2 & \quad 2< t < 3 \\
             0& \quad 3< t < 4 \\           
   -2 & \quad 5< t < 6
        \end{array}
    \right.              $$

Following is my method:

$$       a_k= \frac{1}{6}   ( \int_{2}^{3} 2 e^{-jkw_0t}dt  + \int_{5}^{6} (-2) e^{-jkw_0t}dt)               $$

$$       a_k= \frac{2}{6}   ( \int_{2}^{3} e^{-jkw_0t}dt  - \int_{5}^{6} e^{-jkw_0t}dt)                           $$

After doing some simplification we get:

$$     a_k= \frac{1}{jk\pi}(e^{-2j\frac{k\pi}{3}}-e^{-jk\pi}+e^{-2jk\pi}-e^{-5j\frac{k\pi}{3}})             $$

I am stuck after this last step.

Comment: I forgot to say you can use  Euler's formula $$e^{jx}=\cos x+j\sin x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
for these two terms
$$e^{-2j\frac{k\pi}{3}}-e^{-5j\frac{k\pi}{3}}$$
let 
$$\alpha-x=-2j\frac{k\pi}{3}~~~;~~~\alpha+x=-5j\frac{k\pi}{3}$$
then 
$$\alpha=-7j\frac{k\pi}{6}~~~;~~~x=-j\frac{k\pi}{2}$$
and therefore
$$e^{-2j\frac{k\pi}{3}}-e^{-5j\frac{k\pi}{3}}=\color{blue}{2je^{-7jk\pi/6}\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: can you explain a bit more.

Comment: We want to make an expression like $$e^{\alpha-x}\pm e^{\alpha+x}=e^{\alpha}\left(e^{-x}\pm e^{x}\right)$$